# Excluding certain post status's from pagination

Tags: pagination, post-status

If a user is logged in and browsing through archives, the current pagination function factors in posts that aren't yet published which can result in page numbers leading to 404 pages.

How can I get the pagination function to only factor in published posts?

This is the pagination function I'm using currently:

```
// Pagination
function ta_page_navi() {
    global $wp_query;
    $bignum = 999999999;
    if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
        return;
    echo '<nav class="pagination">';

        echo paginate_links( array(
            'base'          => str_replace( $bignum, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link($bignum) ) ),
            'format'        => '',
            'current'       => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'total'         => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
            'prev_text'     => '←',
            'next_text'     => '→',
            'type'          => 'list',
            'end_size'      => 3,
            'mid_size'      => 3
        ) );

    echo '</nav>';
} /* end pagination */
```

Comment: how are you showing posts on the front end that aren't published? that isn't normal behavior.

Comment: The unpublished posts aren't showing, a 404 page is showing. But the pagination still factors in the unpublished posts when a user is logged into wordpress.

Comment: that should not be the case, you'll have to do some debugging and figure out what is causing that to happen- some theme code or a plugin.

Comment: I suspect that you are running a custom query. You should have a look at that query

Comment: You guys were right, caused by something else. Pagination was fine.